# Animating UITableView resize

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, core-animation

Im using the following code to animate the resizing of a `UITableView` to make way for a `UIView` with extra controls when the UITableView.isEditing.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 // 0.2 but slowed down to easily see difference
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
                 animations:^{
                     [self.selectControlsView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.size.height-self.selectControlsView.frame.size.height, self.selectControlsView.frame.size.width, self.selectControlsView.frame.size.height)];
                     [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height-self.selectControlsView.frame.size.height)];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

This works fine except it seems the `UITableView` animates faster than the `UIView` does (even though I adjust the UIViews frame before the `UITableViews` frame), causing a black flicker during the animation from the background.

Is there a way to animate the two views in tandem?

Comment: I could use two separate animation blocks and have a slight delay on the block for the UITableView animation, but this seems like a bit of a hack. Any better ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because the controller was a subclass of UITableViewController. I'm now subclassing UIViewController and adding the UITableView as a subview, the animation for adding the new view and resizing the UITableView now works as expected.